# Modifying global variables from threaded functions and still run the main thread to use the Global varibales

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, boost, gdi+

I have a project in Visual C++ 2010 where I have to draw some circles and lines. The coordinates of the circles depend on two global variables. The global variables are modified from two functions, each running in their own thread. Boost is used for multi-threading.
However, as soon as I run the threads, my main thread is blocked, thus preventing me from drawing the shapes and using the global variables. How can I get around this? What I ultimately want to achieve is, modify the global variables from two seperate functions running in their own thread and simultaneously draw the circles using the said global varibales

```
global_variable_1
global_variable_2

void function_1()
{
    while(true)
    {
    //modifies global_variable_1
    }
}

void function_2()
{
    while(true)
    {
    //modifies global_variable_2
    }
}

void MyOnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Pen pen(Color::Blue);

    /* Uses global_variable_1 & global_variable_2 to
    draw circles */
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(......)
{
    /* Some initial code */

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
    return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_GAZEPOINTEVALUATION));

    /*Start threads*/
    using namespace boost;

    thread thread_1(function_1);

    thread thread_2(function_2);

    //Start threads
    thread_1.join()
    thread_2.join()

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            /* Some code */
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            /*CALL MY DRAWING METHOD*/
            MyOnPaint(hdc);   
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            /* Some code */
        default:
            /* Some code */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't mind reading dirty values for the global variables because of threading issues. Forgot to mention that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` calls will never return because your threads loop for ever.  From the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.join):

> In order to wait for a thread of execution to finish, the join(),
>   __join_for or __join_until ( timed_join() deprecated) member functions of the boost::thread object must be used. join() will block the
>   calling thread until the thread represented by the boost::thread
>   object has completed.

You never enter your message loop, therefore.

If you remove the join calls, this should do something more like what you expect - in a more complex application you'd need to properly design thread scheduling and exit handling. Even as it stands, you will likely have to add some delay into the spawned threads to avoid pegging the CPU and possibly seeing other weirdness you are not expecting.